# How to have a run screen for each script

Tags: pycharm

This question refers to the "Run" screen in PyCharm:
[image]

Whenever I run a new script it overrides the log from the previous one, but when I have 2 scripts running simultaneously (as in the snippet above), PyCharm would create a second "view" in the run bar (script1 and script2 are the files I ran and each has it's own view)

If a script has finished running, and I run another one - the default behavior is to override the view (or log) of the already ended script.

How do I prevent this default behavior and make PyCharm create a new view for each script, thus keeping the log of the previously ran ones?

Answer (score 0):

You can just pin the script you ran and run your new script and the result will open in a new tab. You can just pin as many tabs as you want and save the results of each run separated from each other and when you need to close any of them just unpin the tab and close it. Hope it helps.